# Show that the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by semi-closed intervals of type (a,b] contains the natural topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm a little confused why this is true. How could the natural topology be a subset of 
  $\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n}A_{\lambda }$ where {$A_{\lambda }$}$_{\lambda \in \Lambda  }$ is a family of subsets of X . 
How could the natural topology be a subset of a semi-closed interval?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are $A_\lambda$s? In addition a topology is a collection of open sets, so to ask "How could the natural topology be a subset of a closed set" is a little odd.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand. Any topology on $\Bbb R$ is never going to be a subset of any subset of $\Bbb R$; it is a subset of the *powerset* of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

The semi-closed subsets are used to *generate* a new topology on $\mathbb{R}$. In other words a set is open in this "semi-closed" topology if it is a union of semi-closed intervals. Just like an open set in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of open intervals.

To see that the semi-closed topology contains all of the old open sets you can show that an open interval is the union of semi-closed intervals. Then the new topology also generates the old topology.

To see this notice that the union of $(a,b-\epsilon]$ where $0<\epsilon<b-a$ is exactly $(a,b)$. Thus $(a,b)$ is open in the new topology. Hence unions of open intervals are open hence all "old" open sets are still open.

Answer (score 1):

$(a,b)=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} (a,b-1/n]$, so the topology generated by the $(a,b]$'s contains the usual topology, which is the smallest topology containing all the $(a,b)$'s.

I am not sure I understand the question "How could the natural topology be a subset of $⋂_{i=1}^n A_λ$ where $\{A_λ\}_{λ∈Λ}$ is a family of subsets of $X$?"  A topology is a set of subsets of $X$, meeting certain conditions. It is thus not a subset of $X$ itself.